# Python- check common elements and their neighbors in two ordered list

Tags: python, list

For two given ordered lists (they can be of different sizes):

```
old_state = [1, 2, 4, 5]
new_state = [1, 3, 2, 5]
```

How can I finds the common elements and classify the elements based on which of their neighbors has changed (in the fastest way possible)?

For example for the above lists the common elements are (1, 2, 5) and their classification would be:

The right neighbor of item *1* has changed from *2* to *3*:

```
RN = [1]
```

both of the neighbors of item *2* have changed *(left neighbor: 1 -> 3, right neighbor: 4 -> 5)*:

```
RLN = [2]
```

and finally left neighbor of item 5 has changed from *4 to 2*:

```
LN = [5]
```

I know the best way to find the common elements is to used set() but when it comes to finding the neighbors I am stuck.

Comment: so what is the output? your `RN`, `RLN`, and `LN` variables simply list the common elements even though you talk about neighbors

Comment: what you intend for ordered list if new_list is not ordered? which are the criteria that make the order change?

Comment: @Lupanoide I didn't mean sorted, by order I meant that each element is used based on their position in the list. For e.g in the new_state first 1 is picked, then 3, then 2 etc.

Comment: @aws the problem was to classify the common elements into three groups (i.e., RN, RLN, LN) based on which of their neighbors has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this does what you need:

```
old_state = [1, 2, 4, 5]
new_state = [1, 3, 2, 5]

RN = []
LN = []
RLN = []

# We iterate through the common elements
common_elements = list(set(old_state).intersection(new_state))
for elem in common_elements:
    # We retrieve the neighbors on both sides
    # First in the old state
    old_index = old_state.index(elem)
    old_state_left = Flase  # Placeholder in case it has no left neighbor
    old_state_right = Flase  # Placeholder in case it has no right neighbor
    if old_index != 0:
        old_state_left = old_state[old_index-1]
    if old_index != len(old_state)-1:
        old_state_right = old_state[old_index+1]

    # Then in the new state
    new_index = new_state.index(elem)
    new_state_left = Flase  # Placeholder in case it has no left neighbor
    new_state_right = Flase  # Placeholder in case it has no right neighbor
    if new_index != 0:
        new_state_left = new_state[new_index-1]
    if new_index != len(new_state)-1:
        new_state_right = new_state[new_index+1]

    # Now we check in which list the element should be
    if new_state_left != old_state_left:
        # Could be LN or RLN
        if new_state_right != old_state_right:
            # Is RLN
            RLN.append(elem)
        else:
            # Is LN
            LN.append(elem)
    elif new_state_right != old_state_right:
        # Is RN
        RN.append(elem)

print(RN)  # outputs [1]
print(RLN)  # outputs [2]
print(LN)  # outputs [5]
```

Comment: It's quite long but I wanted it to be as clear as possible, to correct it in case it's not what you asked for.

Comment: Thank you very much @francisco this is exactly what I was asking. I can't appreciate it enough.